# Why does my BootsFaces not render anything?

Tags: jsf, frameworks, xhtml, bootsfaces

I am fairly new to Coding with Frameworks. I want to build a Website using JSF and found BootsFaces as a Framework. So I downloaded BootsFaces and followed https://www.bootsfaces.net/quick-start.jsf to get everything going. I added the .jar into the Java Build Path and started a Project like the quick-start. So far so good. Then I wanted to implement some more "advanced" stuff. So I tried to add https://showcase.bootsfaces.net/forms/buttonGroups.jsf just to test if everything works. It didn't, If I copy

```
  <b:buttonGroup>
  <b:button value="Left" />
  <b:button value="Middle" />
  <b:button value="Right" />
  </b:buttonGroup>
```

My Site doesnt show anything when it loads.

Here is my index.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head>
    <title>Basic Page</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <b:buttonGroup>
        <b:button value="Left" />
        <b:button value="Middle" />
        <b:button value="Right" />
    </b:buttonGroup>
</h:body>

</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>Mew</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>BootsFaces_USETHEME</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

I use Glassfish as a Server if thats important.
Did I forget/not see something very basic? Or isn't BootsFaces even supposed to work like this?

Comment: So a plain jsf component does work?

Comment: @Kukeltje something like h1? Yes that works

Comment: h1 is plain html.... not plain jsf.... Maybe start with a plain jsf tutorial and then if the basics work, add bootsfaces

Comment: <h:selectOneRadio id="userwahl" value="#{users.usergruppe}" layout="pageDirection">
<f:selectItem itemValue="admin" itemLabel="example"></f:selectItem>” 
<f:selectItem itemValue="common" itemLabel="example2"></f:selectItem>”
</h:selectOneRadio>
@Kukeltje do you mean something more like this?

Comment: yes something, like that  (and it would have been 'quicker' if you added the result)

Comment: @Kukeltje I'm sorry! To come back to my initial question, should BootsFaces work with my setup theoretically? Or isn't it supposed to work like that?

Comment: That was not your original question. You stated that it did not render anything and I asked if plain jsf works. You still did not answer that question.

Comment: @Kukeltje Yes, plain jsf does work.Sorry again

Comment: so with a bootsfaces component, on the cliemt side in the html source you see the  same in the xhtml facelet on the server? If so check if the bootsfaces jar is actually in your runtime deployed webapp